Running a Windows VM on Ubuntu 22.04 host
Is there a way to run a Windows 11 VM with Ubuntu 22.04 as host?
I have been trying to find a solution online, where the only thing I have attempted so far has been installing a windows 11 iso on virtualbox
If someone could guide me I would appreciate it!

You've just answered it - VirtualBox is the easiest way, QEMU-KVM is an alternative option. VMware Workstation for personal use is a third way.  Is there something wrong with the solution you found?  Windows 11 also has some requirements - UEFI, Secure Boot (if possible), and at least TPM on the VM (which you can add in customization of the VM, and it's different for each virtualization platform)
